# A question regarding Determinants

Tags: matrices

Can anyone tell me if the following is true?? Here Det = determinant an I is Sqt[-1]……

LIM ω→0 (1/2I)[ 1/Det(ω-Iδ)  -1/Det(ω+Iδ)  ] =δ(Det(ω))

Comment: Is this a Mathematic question or should you be on Mathematics stack exchange? If you wish to use the computer program Mathematica you should put your question in Mathematic format so that we can copy and paste. I think we need more information on omega.

Answer (score 1):

No, this
$$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac 1{2i}\left[\frac 1{\text{det}(\omega -i\delta)} - \frac 1{\text{det}(\omega +i\delta)}\right] = \delta\,\text{det}(\omega)$$
is obviously not true, for a very simple reason.

The right-hand side of the equality depends on the value of $\omega$. But on the left-hand side, $\omega$ is just a dummy variable. The LH expression does not depend on $\omega$ at all.

In fact, the equation commits a mathematical faux pas, in that it uses $\omega$ to mean two different things in the same context. On the left it is a dummy variable, but on the right, it is a free variable with its own set value. These uses are not compatible.

As a dummy variable, any other unused variable could be substituted in place of $\omega$ on the left. For example, your equation could also be written as
$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac 1{2i}\left[\frac 1{\text{det}(\alpha -i\delta)} - \frac 1{\text{det}(\alpha +i\delta)}\right] = \delta\,\text{det}(\omega)$$
Where is is clear that the LH and RH sides cannot be equal.